# postfix + amazon ses - How to hold all emails?

Tags: postfix, amazon-ses

I have postfix configured to send all email using Amazon's SES perl script.

- How can I modify the configuration to hold all email?
- Is it possible to re-queue bounced emails?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Somewhere in recipient_restrictions insert
  `recipient_restrictions = ... static:HOLD ...`
- As the name says "bounced" mails are bounced mails. It is the past. They are already gone (back to sender) so there is nothing to re-queue. If you instead mean how to re-queue a mail on hold then this is done by `postsuper -r <mailid>`